# {"message":"no Route matched with those values"}

Tags: proxy, forwarding, kong

I am new to Kong so bear with me:)
I am hosting my APIs on a windows server as http://supermarket.xxxx.com:5000

added service as follows on an Ubuntu box (http://supermarket.xxxx.com is added to hosts file)

```
 curl -i -X POST
 --url http://localhost:8001/services/
 --data 'name=SupermarketService'
 --data 'url=http://supermarket.xxx.com:5000'
```

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 07:11:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: kong/2.1.3
Content-Length: 379
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 204

2 Added the routes

```
curl -i -X POST
--url http://localhost:8001/services/SupermarketService/routes
--data 'hosts[]=supermarket.xxx.com'
--data 'paths[]=/api/categories'
--data 'strip_path=false'
--data 'methods[]=GET'
```

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 09:01:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: kong/2.1.3
Content-Length: 463
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 11

testing the setting on the Ubuntu box

```
curl -i -X GET
--url http://localhost:8000/api/categories
--header 'Host: supermarket.xxx.com'
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' ; connect-src 'self' data: *;
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 23:10:21 GMT
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 1586
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 2
Via: kong/2.1.3

[{"id":100,"name":"Fruits and Vegetables"},{"id":101,"name":"Dairy"}]

when I try to access the same API in another box using a web browser
http://192.168.44.67:8000/api/categories //where 192.168.44.67 is the IP address of my Ubuntu box
iI get this
{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}

Please let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

when accessing the API from the other box using a webbrowser you didn't set the `Host` header. Since when using a webbrowser the browser will automatically set that header based on the url you type in the browser url bar.

remove the following element from the curl request to create the route:

```
--data 'hosts[]=supermarket.xxx.com'
```

Then it will only match on the path segment you provided and it should work